# How to code this data into JSON and access it

Tags: json

```
{
    "hospitalID": 1,
    "hospitalName": "KG Hospital",
    "hospitalLocation": "North",
    "vaccinesAvailable": "500",
    "hospitalAddress": "205, Race Course , Coimbatore"
},
{
    "hospitalID": 2,
    "hospitalName": "KMCH Hospital",
    "hospitalLocation": "South",
    "vaccinesAvailable": "1500",
    "hospitalAddress": "205,Avinashi Road , Coimbatore"
},
{
    "hospitalID": 3,
    "hospitalName": "Kongunadu Hospital",
    "hospitalLocation": "East",
    "vaccinesAvailable": "800",
    "hospitalAddress": "25, Gandhipuram , Coimbatore"
},
{
    "hospitalID": 4,
    "hospitalName": "PSG Hospital",
    "hospitalLocation": "West",
    "vaccinesAvailable": "500",
    "hospitalAddress": "205, Avinashi Road , Coimbatore"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 653

{ "hospitalID": 1, "hospitalName": "KG Hospital", "hospitalLocation": "North", "vaccinesAvailable": "500", "hospitalAddress": "205, Race Course , Coimbatore" }, { "hospitalID": 2, "hospitalName": "KMCH Hospital", "hospitalLocation": "South", "vaccinesAvailable": "1500", "hospitalAddress": "205,Avinashi Road , Coimbatore" }, { "hospitalID": 3, "hospitalName": "Kongunadu Hospital", "hospitalLocation": "East", "vaccinesAvailable": "800", "hospitalAddress": "25, Gandhipuram , Coimbatore" }, { "hospitalID": 4, "hospitalName": "PSG Hospital", "hospitalLocation": "West", "vaccinesAvailable": "500", "hospitalAddress": "205, Avinashi Road , Coimbatore" }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is a sequence of comma-separated JSON values. One way to transform this into valid JSON would be to add a pair of matching square brackets, one at the head, and the other at the tail.
There are countless ways to do this, but you might find a tool such as [any-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-json) convenient.

Depending on the context, you might wish to transform this comma-separated-JSON into a stream of JSON objects, by removing the commas separating the (top-level) JSON objects. That, however, would probably be done most easily by first adding the square brackets as above, and then using a JSON-oriented tool such as [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to produce the stream.  Assuming the comma-separated-JSON is in a file, input.txt:

```
$ echo '{'; cat input.txt; echo '}' | jq -c .[]
```

```
{"hospitalID":1,"hospitalName":"KG Hospital","hospitalLocation":"North","vaccinesAvailable":"500","hospitalAddress":"205, Race Course , Coimbatore"}
{"hospitalID":2,"hospitalName":"KMCH Hospital","hospitalLocation":"South","vaccinesAvailable":"1500","hospitalAddress":"205,Avinashi Road , Coimbatore"}
{"hospitalID":3,"hospitalName":"Kongunadu Hospital","hospitalLocation":"East","vaccinesAvailable":"800","hospitalAddress":"25, Gandhipuram , Coimbatore"}
{"hospitalID":4,"hospitalName":"PSG Hospital","hospitalLocation":"West","vaccinesAvailable":"500","hospitalAddress":"205, Avinashi Road , Coimbatore"}
```